# Digital Ocean post request with JSON input returns blank in plumber API

Tags: r, digital-ocean, plumber

My plumber function runs properly in local ( creating two R sessions and sending post request from one to other works ). However when doing the same for digitalocean server it is returning empty sting.

**Plumber API**

```
# plumber.R


#* @post /
#* @get /
function(req){
  
  tryCatch({
  
  list( rawbody = req$postBody )

  }, error = function(e) {

        return( jsonlite::toJSON( list('error' = e), force = T ) )
  })
  
}
```

**POST request**

```
rm( list = ls() )

library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# url for local testing
url <- "http://127.0.0.1:6531"   #... have changed URL to server url when testing for server

body = list( 'msg' = 'hi' )

# set API path
path <- 'data'

# send POST Request to API
raw.result <- POST(url = url, path = path, body = body, encode = 'json')

# check status code
raw.result$status_code

# check response
fromJSON(rawToChar(raw.result$content))
```

Please note GET request works fine but sending data with JSON doesn't work.

**Output for server url**

```
fromJSON(rawToChar(raw.result$content))
$rawbody
[1] ""
```

**Output from local url**

```
fromJSON(rawToChar(raw.result$content))
$rawbody
[1] "hi"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried changing  the `url` for  `0.0.0.0:6531`?

Comment: It gives address not available.